# Google Web App script which add new column with header to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small script which add new column. Unfortunately it add a column in wrong place and without header. What I need to add to get a column with increasing number in header?

[Screen-shot from spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULtP5.png)

At the moment I have:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sh.insertColumns(1);
}
```

Comment: What is your existing code?

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: I edited my queston with code.

Answer (score 2):

This code adds a column after the last column that contains a value. The header becomes `Obciązenie [num] tyg.` per your screenshot example.

```js
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = sh.getLastColumn();
  var colContents = sh.getRange(1, col).getValue();
  var previousHeaderNum = colContents.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');
  var headerNum = (parseInt(previousHeaderNum, 10) +1);
  var header = "Obciązenie " + headerNum + " tyg."

  sh.insertColumnAfter(col);
  sh.getRange(1, col+1).setValue(header);
}
```

#### Explanation:

- Retrieve the index of the last column with content using [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()).
- Retrieve last column header value using [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) and [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()).
- Retrieve the number from the header value, for example using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and add 1 to that.
- Insert column to first empty column using [insertColumnAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertcolumnafterafterposition), and set the header value using [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)).